# Python: How to prevent the implicit removal of diacritical marks from Unicode characters during keyboard input

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I'm using Python 2.7 in Windows.

In the Python command-line, when I entered this:

```py
u'À'
```

The output became this:

```py
u'A'
```

Somehow, the diacritical marks of some characters are removed. How do I prevent this from happening?

In my case, the encoding for `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` without custom configuration is `'cp437'`.

Things I've tried (but didn't work):

- This:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs
import sys
sys.stdin = codecs.getreader('utf-8')(sys.stdin)
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)
```

- Setting an environment variable named `PYTHONIOENCODING` with the value `utf-8`.

Comment: What happens when you try a non-ancient version?

Comment: “I’m using Python 2.7”. Don’t. It’s actually a Python 2/Windows issue, but it’s fixed in recent Python 3s

Comment: [@Mark Tolonen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235698/mark-tolonen), can you show me a link to a discussion or documentation about the issue you mentioned?